# Is the dual of the space of section of a vector bundle Isomorphic to the space of section of the dual bundle?

Tags: vector-bundles, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

Let $(M, E, \pi, \cdot,+)$ be a vector bundle and let $(M, E^*, \pi, \times,*)$ be a the dual bundle. Denote $\Gamma(E)$ and $\Gamma(E^*)$ their respective space of section.

Now let $\Gamma(E)^*$ denote the dual of  $\Gamma(E)$ .

Is $\Gamma(E)^*$ isomorphic to $\Gamma(E^*)$ ? If so how to proof this isomorphism ?

Comment: It seems that $\Gamma(E)^\ast$ is the dual of $\Gamma(E)$ as a vector space over the base field $\mathbb{R}$.
Consider when $E=M \times \mathbb{R}$. Then $E\cong E^\ast$ as a vector bundle over $M$ and $\Gamma(E^\ast)\cong\Gamma(E)\cong C^{\infty}(M)$, while $\Gamma(E)^\ast$ is isomorphic to the dual space of $C^{\infty}(M)$. Now, since $C^{\infty}(M)$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, its dual is strictly larger.
However, if you meant $\Gamma(E)^\ast := Hom_{C^{\infty}(M)}(\Gamma(E), C^{\infty}(M))$, (i.e. dual over $C^{\infty}(M)$) then they are isomorphic.